# RXJS filter on another observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my code I am getting a list of users from [MS Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list), but this lists all users.  I want to emit only those users that are a member of a specified group.  So I have set up a filter:

```
private loadUsers() {
    console.log(`Loading users...`);
    this.graph.get$(`users`)
        .map(resp => resp.json().value)
        .flatMap(user => user)
        .do(user => {
            console.log(`Got user: ${user['displayName']}`);
        })
        .filter(user => {
            // we only want users who are members of the TrackerContact group
            const userId: string = user['id'];
            console.log(`Checking user ${userId}`);
            return this.userIsTrackerContact(user); // <<= PROBLEM HERE!
        })
        .subscribe(_ => {
            console.log(`Completed user fetch!`);
        });
}
```

The problem is in order to find out what groups a user is a member of, I must make another REST call back to [MS Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof):

```
private userIsTrackerContact(user): Observable<boolean> {
    // get the groups this user is a member of
    return this.graph.get$(`users/${user['id']}/memberOf`)
        .map(resp => resp.json().value)
        .do(groups => {
            console.log(`${user['displayName']} is a member of ${groups.length} groups:`);
            groups.forEach((group, idx) => {
                console.log(`   [${idx+1}]: ${group['displayName']}`);
            })
        })
        .map(groups => {
            const found = groups.find((group) => group['id'] === this.authConfig.azureGroups.trackerContact)
            return !isUndefined(found);
        })
}
```

It does not seem to me that it's possible to [filter](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) an Observable based on another observable.  The predicate test must be a simple true/false test.

How can I filter an Observable based on the results of another Observable?

Comment: you need to filter this at your service end in order to have a light weight data. Both of them are executed simultaneously or ?

Comment: I have to agree with @Aravind. It is more efficient to ask the server for a collection of users already filtered then to get a larger collection of users and then to make a http request for each user just to filter them.

Comment: @stely000:  While I agree in principal, and I actually solved this problem using a completely different technique, I guess the question remains.  What if there is no other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.concatAll() might be better:

```
this.graph.get$(`users`)
    .map(resp => resp.json().value)
    .flatMap(user => user)
    .do(user => {
        console.log(`Got user: ${user['displayName']}`);
    })
    .filter(user => {
        // we only want users who are members of the TrackerContact group
        const userId: string = user['id'];
        console.log(`Checking user ${userId}`);
        return this.userIsTrackerContact(user); // <<= PROBLEM HERE!
    })
    .concatAll()
    .subscribe(...)
```

I believe you should be able to [merge](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/merge.md) the async observables then filter.

```
Rx.Observable.merge(this.graph.get$(`users`)
    .map(resp => resp.json().value)
    .flatMap(user => user)
    .do(user => {
        console.log(`Got user: ${user['displayName']}`);
    })
    .map(user => {
        // we only want users who are members of the TrackerContact group
        const userId: string = user['id'];
        console.log(`Checking user ${userId}`);
        return this.userIsTrackerContact(user); // <<= PROBLEM HERE!
    }))
    .filter(x => x)
    .subscribe(_ => console.info('success'));
```

You can change your predicate set a property on user isGroupMember. Then `filter(x => x.isGroupMember)`. Then you have the user objects in the subscribe method.

Comment: I ended up going a completely different direction with this and implemented a solution I'm much happier with.  What I ended up doing was firing off 3 Observables, converted them all to Promises, and then did an `.all([...])` on all three.  Those three promises returned all the data I needed.  However I'm still going to accept this answer because it seems right in the case where there really is no alternative.